# Link an `a` tag with `href` in a django form HTML

Tags: html, django, forms

I have a django form and I am trying to create a step up form where when you finish one section you click next to the go the next section in the same HTML template:

I have created everything fine but I am stuck with the button for the next button. I have set an `id` and linked it to an `href` but is not opening the next form as required.

Here is what I have tried to make it easier for explaining:

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="ex-3" role="tablist">
            <!-- General Information -->
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="ex-3-tab-1" data-mdb-toggle="pill"
                href="#generalInformation"
                role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-selected="true"
                >General Information</a>
            </li>
            <!-- Contact Information -->
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                id="tab_contactInformation"
                data-mdb-toggle="pill"
                href="#contactInformation"
                role="tab" aria-controls="pills-2" aria-selected="false"
                >Contact Information</a
              >
            </li>
        </ul>
```

In the General info part I have added an `a` tag to link to `href="#contactInformation"` same as the nav-pill showing in the top but it is not leading to it. It is just saying in the same location.

```
                    <a
                      href="#contactInformation"
                      >Contact Information</a
                    >
```

**My question**

How to add an `a` tag with `href` linking to the next part? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Thanks for the explanation in advance to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you want to move to another section when you click on the 'a' tag. You can try to create a div tag with the 'id' as 'contactInformation', as the hashtag, if I remember correctly, links to an 'id' value. So if you were to keep #contactInformation, you will want to have a div tag with the id='contactInformation'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about multi step form :-

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Full Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Source :- [W3 Schools Multi Step Form](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create section and give id for section

if you click Contact Section it takes yo into contact section you can use is as menu and menu sections here code:

```
<a href="#contact">Contact Section</a>

<section id="contact">

<h5>Address</h5>
<h5>Phone</h5>
<p>some text</p>

</section>
```